# PostgreSQL join display duplicate

Tags: database, postgresql, relation

I have problem with table join, when I do join the return results is duplicated.

Table A Fields :

```
id, name, acccount_number, account_number_other, customer_service_id, temporary, weight, created_at, updated_at
```

With row :

```
1, X, 1234, 6543, 1, false, 5, '2017-12-12 19:51:06','2017-12-12 19:51:06'
```

Table B Fields :

```
id, name, account_number, branch_id, type, transaction, total, a_id, created_at, updated_at.
```

With rows :

```
1, Y, 5232, 1, Z, 1000, 1000, 1, '2017-12-12 19:51:06', '2017-12-12 19:51:06'
2, Y, 5232, 1, Z, 1000, 1000, 1, '2017-12-12 20:11:00', '2017-12-12 20:11:00'
```

My query is :

```
SELECT a.id, a.name, a.weight, b.transaction, b.total, b.name as reference,
    b..type, b.id as reference_id, b.account_number
FROM a INNER JOIN b
    ON b.a_id = a.id
WHERE b.branch_id = 1 AND temporary = false
ORDER BY a.weight DESC, b.total DESC, b.transaction DESC;
```

But, the result is duplicated.... Because there is a 2 rows on table B joined with table A... And I just wanted to displaying 1 row with conditions only select last created_at row from table B.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
SELECT id, name, weight, transaction, total, reference, type, reference_id,
    account_number
FROM
(
    SELECT a.id, a.name, a.weight, b.transaction, b.total, b.name as reference,
        b.type, b.id as reference_id, b.account_number,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY b.id ORDER BY b.created_at DESC) rn
    FROM a
    INNER JOIN b
         ON b.a_id = a.id
    WHERE b.branch_id = 1 AND temporary = false
) t
WHERE t.rn = 1
ORDER BY
    weight DESC, total DESC, transaction DESC;
```

For each `id` value in table B, this will choose the record corresponding to the most recent `created_at` value.